# What to reply to "祝你好运" (I wish you good luck)?

Tags: usage, informal

Does "祝你好运!" expect any "predefined" reply? Which one?
If not, what should be replied?
Would just "谢谢" be appropriate?

Comment: It would be perfectly fine. You can always reciprocate: “谢谢, 我也祝你好运！”

Comment: That's fine, or reply "你也好运".

Comment: Sometimes, “你也好运” is not appropriate. For example, you are going to take an exam, your teacher says to you “祝你好运”. “Thank you”just be appropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

“祝你好运” means “Good luck!”
“谢谢”Just be appropriate.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Do you mean that one can say "祝你好运" to a third person, too? Or to multiple people? Could be used ironically, too?

Comment: @Starnutoditopo yes! Everyone like luck.